# Constructing an organized utility from jquery

Tags: jquery, oop, javascript

I am currently organizing all of my utility scripts into one object. I would like to unify the way they work by having the api/ signature of each method look and act basically the same. Here is what I mean by this:

```
$('#someID').utils.someFunc1('param')

and also

$('#someID').utils.someObj.someClass('param');
```

In ANY instance when this util object is accessed, I want to ensure that the last method on the chain has a refference to `$(this)` the same as normal, however I am stuck trying to get this to work. Another words in the last example I would like the `someClass()` class to have access to the `$('#someID')` `$.object` the same as a traditional jQuery plugin proxies `$(this)`.

Heres my code:

```
$.fn.toolkit = new Object();

$.fn.toolkit.Show = function(){
  var target = $(this);
    target.css('display','block');
    return this;
}

$.fn.toolkit.Hide = function(){
  var target = $(this);
    target.css('display','none');
    return this;
}



// doesnt work :(
$('button').toolkit.Hide()
```

Comment: If I'm understanding the question correctly, I don't think this is possible.

Comment: Basically no matter how deep I chain the methods, I would like to ensure that the method at the end keeps ref to $(this) as it would if the main module was a function instead of an object

Comment: you can't do that (easily). I recall seeing someone develop a complex framework that somehow managed to get that kind of chaining working, but it involved hooking deep into jQuery's internal methods. Far more overhead than it is worth in my opinion.

Comment: I can accomplish this by $.fn.someStuff.someMethod = function(){ .. this.util = function(){....}  } but I do not want to have the var util = new $.fn.toolkit; var someInstanceName = util.Hide() but this is extra code that I would like to avoid if possible

Comment: Right, but how are you going to get access to the element?

Comment: @KevinB via $(this) like a traditional jQuery plugin (at the begining of the chain)

Comment: That isn't possible, as you have demonstrated in your question. You would have to override jquery's constructor to store the selected element somewhere where your plugin can access it.

Comment: That sounds like it shouldnt be too hard... is that an inaccurate assumption? Could $(this) be proxied using $.proxy?

Comment: The problem is, none of your code executes until the Show method, at which point there is no longer a way to access the selected element. There is no place for you to proxy it other than where it already no longer exists.

Comment: I would instead create my own constructor and use that as the namespace rather than attaching it to the jQuery prototype. I could post an example as an answer, but that wouldn't even remotely answer the question that was asked